# 4 pics 1 word game answer explain

Tags: visual, word-game

How the four pics resembles alphabet. Can anyone explain? I can only see there is just some Greek letters like omega and pi and one soup picture?

[image: puzzle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see much logic here, but as the puzzle is Greek:

> Letter (Pi - $\pi$), Letter (Omega - $\Omega$), Alpha-Omega (English A-Z), Greek Alphabet Soup, put all four together - **ALPHABET**. A bit weak maybe?

Comment: I like the interpretation of ΑΩ as the entire alphabet Α-Ω instead of them being two separate letters

Answer (score 0):

The four pictures have one common theme:

> the alphabet.

Starting in the upper left corner, going clockwise, we have

> 1. the Greek letter $\pi$
>  2. the Greek letter $\Omega$
>  3. [**alphabet** soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_pasta)
>  4. the Greek letters $A$ (alpha) and $\Omega$

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered your own question yourself... In the first picture you see Pi, which is the greek letter equivalent to the English P; in the second, you see Omega, which is the last letter of the Greek alphabet, and is pronounced similarly to a long "o"; in the third, you see an A and an Omega, which belong respectively to the modern English alphabet and the Greek alphabet; and lastly, you have a spoonful of letter soup.

Answer (score 0):

The Pie is the alphabet (letter P in Greek)
The Omega is the letter (O) in Greek
A and Omega are both from alphabet (A from Latin and Omega is O in Greek alphabet)
The bowl contains alphabet which is Alphabet cereal stock (google it)